# Segmentation Fault (core dump) with Files (C- linux)

Tags: c, linux

I'm getting a segmentation error (core dump) when I try to run this. It compiles perfectly but I get the error, and I don't know why. There must be a problem with a file writing because without this works good. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{

FILE *f=fopen("shadow1.txt","w");


  if (f=NULL)
  {
    printf("ERROR");

  }


  unsigned long seed[2];
  char salt[] = "$1$........";
  const char *const seedchars =
    "./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST"
    "UVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  char *password;
  int i;

  /* Generate a (not very) random seed.
     You should do it better than this... */
  seed[0] = time(NULL);
  seed[1] = getpid() ^ (seed[0] >> 14 & 0x30000);

  /* Turn it into printable characters from ‘seedchars’. */
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    salt[3+i] = seedchars[(seed[i/5] >> (i%5)*6) & 0x3f];

  /* Read in the user’s password and encrypt it. */
  password = crypt(getpass("Password:"), salt);

  /* Print the results. */
  //fprintf(f,"%s $ %s",password);
  printf("Success Registration to file !");
  fclose(f);
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: it is in linux , so i dont have debugger...

Comment: `sudo apt install gdb` should do the trick.

Comment: Compile (and link) your program with the `-g` option.  Instead of running "`./myprogram`", run "`gdb myprogram`".  Type "`run`".  Your program will run, and hopefully crash in the same way.  Type "`bt`" (backtrace).  gdb will show you exactly where your program crashed.  Often this is enough to figure out the problem.

Comment: "lab3.c:46:59: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘crypt’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] password = crypt(getpass("Create Password:"), s);" Wait, what is the signature of crypt?

Comment: @N00byEdge the general Function of crypt is : `char * crypt_r (const char *key, const char *salt, struct crypt_data * data)` but wrong isnt in crypt...because i run it without files and works ...

Comment: Do not use scanf to get strings. Actually not using scanf at all is not a bad policy. It's very, very rarely the best function for a problem.

Comment: "Compiles perfectly". Bad news for you today, sorry. Perfectly means NO warnings. Compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` *at least* to reduce wastage of time.

Comment: look the edited , question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if (f=NULL)
  {
    printf("ERROR");

  }
```

was the problem...

Answer (score 1):

`void Register(char u,char p) {`

you probably want these to be `char *` because of the `fprintf` that treats them as strings:

`fprintf(f,"%s $ %s",u,p);`

and since you pass `char *`s in:

```
char *password,*username;
//...
Register(username,password);
```

This would most likely have been caught by compiler warnings. It is a lot faster to get your answer from the compiler than from here.

If you can't figure out why your program isn't working, you can enable all the warnings you should need with `-Wall -Wextra` and turn warnings into errors with `-Werror`.

Comment: Did you change the forward declaration in the main function as well as in the implementation?

Comment: yes...  i have in edit some warnings if they can help

Answer (score 1):

You are not allocating space to hold username so it will segfault on the scanf.

Comment: What he is saying is that you need a buffer and to pass the address of said buffer. char buf[]; scanf("%79s", buf);

Comment: i put in comment username in order to see if this is the problem , but error still exists...

Comment: You are also not allocating memory for password unless your crypt function is doing it. And like the other comment your if f=null is wrong it assigns null to f instead of checking its value, use == to compare.